# Two if statements inside startTimer()

Tags: javascript

Below is the countdown timer. When I use two if statemtns the time jumps 2 seconds by 2 seconds. How do I add two if statemtns and keep the countdown normal (so the time changes every second instead of two seconds)

```
function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

        if (--timer < 0.5) {
            alert("less than ½ minute")
        } else if (--timer < 0) {
            alert("completed")
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

[FIddle](https://jsfiddle.net/NathaliaZeed/wr1ua0db/177/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lose the extra decrement (`--`), and check for `< 0` first - otherwise you'll never see the `< 0` case, since `< 0.5` will also be true (and checked first).

```
--timer;

if (timer < 0) {
  alert("completed")
}
else if (timer < 0.5) {
  alert("less than ½ minute")
}
```

Comment: thanks. that worked. Is it better to have a `clearInterval();` inside `if (timer < 0) { ... }`?